# Error when trying to gap-fill Landsat 7 images

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, landsat-7

I am trying to gap-fill Landsat 7 images in Google Earth Engine.  I was hoping to just add a function to some existing code (see below) but I end up getting an error message of:

Line 12: filtered.focal_mean is not a function

I am working with a time-series of images (essentially an image from each month) and have just tried to initially gap-fill the first one (2012-04-24).
I am still pretty new to GEE.

```
var proj = ee.Projection('EPSG:4283');
var start = ee.Date('2012-04-24'); 
var startT2 = ee.Date('2012-05-26');  
var range = (16);
var cloudLimit = (100);                  
var scale = (30);                     
Map.centerObject(darwin);
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance( range, 'days')); 
var dateRangeT2 = ee.DateRange(startT2, startT2.advance( range, 'days')); 
var filtered = l7.filterDate(dateRange).filterBounds(darwin).sort('CLOUD_COVER',false).select(['SR_B7', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2']);  
var img_fill = filtered.focal_mean(1, 'square', 'pixels', 8)
```

Comment: `.focal_mean` is a method of an Image.  `filtered` is an ImageCollection, not an Image. You need to map the focal_mean to each Image in the collection https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_mapping

Comment: Example http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/time-series-on-landsat-data-gee/#:~:text=B3%27%2C%20%27B2%27%2C%20%27B1%27%5D)%3B-,The%20problem%20with%20Landsat%207%20ETM,-Here%20is%20the

Comment: Thank you for this advice; it makes things much clearer.